# FoS5 - Twig - How to change input attr_ name of Twig Form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, input, twig

I use symfony 5 and Twig and I created a login form with twig but the problem is their input attr_ name. I have some `form[username]` (by example) but I want `_username`. How can I change that?

I have :

```
<input type='text' name='login[username]'> FROM {{ form_widget(login.username) }}
```

I want :

```
<input type='text' name='_username'>
```

Thanks a lot :D

B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the form names directly (either in the twig view or in the LoginType depending on the method used) and retrieve the corresponding names in your Authentificator (file to create or extend)  :

```
public function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request->request->get('login')['email'], // email, or _email, or username, or _username, etc.
        'password' => $request->request->get('login')['password'],
        'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('login')['_token'],
    ];

    $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $credentials['email']);

    return $credentials;
}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

Comment: Hello ! Thank you but now I have this error `Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null]`